# Python __attrs__ explained

Tags: python

I am going through the code of Python `requests` library from Kenneth Reitz (which is awesome!). And I have encountered a Class variable named `__attrs__` (see below). Tried to find out something about it via Google and SymbolHound, but no luck.

Is this a standard Python thing? Where can I find more infos? Can someone enlighten me?

From: https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/sessions.py

```
class Session(SessionRedirectMixin):
    ...

    __attrs__ = [
        'headers', 'cookies', 'auth', 'proxies', 'hooks', 'params', 'verify',
        'cert', 'prefetch', 'adapters', 'stream', 'trust_env',
        'max_redirects',
    ]

    def __init__(self):

        #: A case-insensitive dictionary of headers to be sent on each
        #: :class:`Request <Request>` sent from this
        #: :class:`Session <Session>`.
        self.headers = default_headers()
```

Comment: It looks like they might have meant to use [`__slots__`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/472000/usage-of-slots)

Comment: @RyanHaining: They set attributes not listed in `__attrs__`, though, such as `self.redirect_cache`. It looks like these are just the attributes they want to serialize in `__getstate__`.

Comment: this is only used for debugging (developer mode), aiohttp uses ATTRS for this

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is not a standard Python thing. As far as I can tell, it's only there to be used in the `__getstate__` method further down the class:

```
def __getstate__(self):
    state = dict((attr, getattr(self, attr, None)) for attr in self.__attrs__)
    state['redirect_cache'] = dict(self.redirect_cache)
    return state
```

The name `__attrs__` is a poor choice, as names beginning and ending with `__` are reserved for core Python language features.

Answer (score 3):

It is not standard, because it is not part of the Python Object Model.

The requests module uses it [here](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/333fa8d3f201f68b82d9e8f26be4987e869fd3bf/requests/models.py#L594) (Response object), too, for reference

It just a way to keep some state hidden (at least as hidden as possible, because *nothing* is truly hidden in Python).

The writers of this code just delegate to this dictionary using a call that *is* part of the Python Object Model `getattr`:

```
return {attr: getattr(self, attr, None) for attr in self.__attrs__}
```

Comment: It should really be `__attrs` then, without the trailing double underscore. Preceding **and** trailing dunders are by convention reserved for core Python features.

Comment: @ASz Fine, but you can take your concerns to the writers of the requests module: [Open new Issue](https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/new/choose)